# Why does heroku rename Build files?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, heroku, unity-webgl

Recently I encountered the following problem.

In my local git repository files have the names starting with `Build*`:

```
$ ls Build/
Build.data.unityweb  Build.wasm.code.unityweb       UnityLoader.js
Build.json           Build.wasm.framework.unityweb
```

When I push master branch to heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```

and connect to see what's there

```
heroku run bash -a name-of-myapp
```

It shows that names start with `BUILD*`

```
~ $ ls Build
ls Build
BUILD.data.unityweb  BUILD.wasm.code.unityweb       UnityLoader.js
BUILD.json           BUILD.wasm.framework.unityweb
```

And my app doesn't work because it looks for files with name `Build*`.

Additional info: I develop in Unity, Windows-platform. Then build an app in Unity to create WebGL app. Than deploy it to heroku. It worked, but have stopped working yesterday.